# z-index не дает работать остальным элементам (выпадающая плашка закрывает ссылку, даже когда она свернута)

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

На сайте есть выдвигающаяся плашечка, она специально выделена на отдельный уровень, но из-за того, что она выше, элементы под ней не хотят работать. Плашечка выдвигается при наведении на нее, а когда на нее не наводят, складывается обратно, но получается что место, которое она занимает в выдвинутом состоянии не дает работать элементам под ней. Даже если она сложена. Как такое можно исправить, подскажите пожалуйста.

```js
$(".menu").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass(" open");
});
```

```css
.home {
  position: relative;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.LA {
  width: 250px;
  left: -180px;
  text-align: right;
  -webkit-transition: left 1s ease-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: left 1s ease-out 0s;
  -o-transition: left 1s ease-out 0s;
  transition: left 1s ease-out 0s;
}

.LA:hover {
  left: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: none;
}

.menu .title::before {
  content: '▶ ';
  font-size: 80%;
  color: green;
}

.menu.open .title::before {
  content: '▼ ';
}

.menu.open ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="position: absolute; z-index: 999;">

  <div class="home LA" onClick="document.location='la.php'">
    <p class="pLA">Тест</p>
  </div>
</div>
    <div style="margin-left: 90px;">
      <div style="position: relative; top: 10px; width: 500px; height: 300px; overflow: scroll;">
        <div class="menu">
          <span class="title">Сладости (нажми меня)!</span>
          <ul>
            <li>Пирог</li>
            <li>Пончик</li>
            <li>Мед</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задайте принудительно ширину для контейнера выдвигающегося блока, например:

```js
$(".menu").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass(" open");
});
```

```css
.home {
  position: relative;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.LA {
  width: 250px;
  left: -180px;
  text-align: right;
  -webkit-transition: left 1s ease-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: left 1s ease-out 0s;
  -o-transition: left 1s ease-out 0s;
  transition: left 1s ease-out 0s;
}

.LA:hover {
  left: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: none;
}

.menu .title::before {
  content: '▶ ';
  font-size: 80%;
  color: green;
}

.menu.open .title::before {
  content: '▼ ';
}

.menu.open ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="position: absolute; z-index: 999;width:1px">

  <div class="home LA" onClick="document.location='la.php'">
    <p class="pLA">Тест</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="margin-left: 90px;">
  <div style="position: relative; top: 10px; width: 500px; height: 300px; overflow: scroll;">
    <div class="menu">
      <span class="title">Сладости (нажми меня)!</span>
      <ul>
        <li>Пирог</li>
        <li>Пончик</li>
        <li>Мед</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```